# difference between "hold something" and "hold with someting" in context

Tags: difference

I heard a person say this:

> I can do this exercise, but I must admit it is pretty difficult to **hold with** this weight.

Would the sentence have the same meaning if the person dropped the word *with*?

Comment: Without further context the meaning is not perfectly clear and we can only make plausible guesses. The meaning might not be the same if you dropped the word **with**, since **hold** can refer to a posture. We cannot say with any certainty.

Comment: In the video an athlete was doing the farmer's walk, that is walking with dumbbells in each hand and hand are straight and down. During the excercise he said: "I can hold with this weight". So did he mean that he could maintain his right posture or as Em put it in their answer to maintain the excersise?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "hand [s] are *straight and down*". Do you mean his arms? And I'm not familiar with "the farmer's walk".  Whatever it means, the statement should mean the same when reversed: "With this weight, I can hold".   **Hold** is not being used transitively there.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I meant arms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the speaker has a weight, like a dumbbell.

In the original, *hold* roughly means *maintain*. *With this weight* roughly means *while holding this weight*. This *hold* is the one that roughly means *grab, grasp*. In other words, it’s difficult to maintain the exercise while grasping the weight.

In your version, *hold* means *grab, grasp*. So the speaker is saying that it’s difficult to grasp the weight.

If the speaker doesn’t have a weight, then *with this weight* could be a comment on the speaker’s body weight. The speaker might be saying that it’s difficult to maintain the exercise while being heavy/fat. In your example, removing the *with* could make the  sentence mean that it’s difficult to maintain his body weight (kilos, pounds).

*Disclaimer.* There might be a dialect where *hold* and *hold with* mean the same thing, *grab, grasp*.